# WiX Toolset - Is there a way to hide Util:XmlFile calls from the log?

Tags: wix, custom-action

Even though I hide the WiX property that contains a password and the ExecXmlFile property...

```
<Property Id="MyApp_MyServer_constr" Hidden="yes" />
<Property Id="ExecXmlFile" Hidden="yes" />

<DirectoryRef Id='MYAPPDIR'>
    <Component Id='UpdateMyAppMyServerConnectionString' Guid='MY-GUID' Win64="yes">
        <CreateFolder />
        <util:XmlFile Id='UpdateMyAppMyServerConnectionString'
                        Action="setValue"
                        ElementPath="[MyServer_elementpath]"
                        File="[MYAPPDIR]MyApp.exe.config"
                        Value="[MyApp_MyServer_constr]" />
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

...password details are exposed in the MSI install log file.

```
MSI (s) (F0:7C) [20:27:56:613]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=ExecXmlFile,,)
Action 20:27:56: ExecXmlFile. 
MSI (s) (F0:7C) [20:27:56:613]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=ExecXmlFile,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=ExecXmlFile,CustomActionData=20C:\Program Files\MyCompany\MyInstallerName\MyApp\MyApp.exe.config30//configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='MyServer']/@connectionStringUser ID=sa;Password=wysiwyg;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Data Source=MACHINE-NAME;Application Name=MyShortAppName)
```

I've done a considerable amount of checking online, but there does seem to be a WiX way of hiding this information from an MSI log without doctoring things using Orca after creating an MSI.

I found this WiX bug http://wixtoolset.org/issues/3859/, but it seems that not allowing hiding of ExecXmlFile CustomAction calls was by design.

Alternately, is there another WiX way to accomplish what I need that doesn't expose password details in the log file?

Thanks

Comment: I think it is reasonable if by design: the password is in plain text in the MSI file and the XML file so why not in the log file also?

Comment: In this instance, it could expose DB Admin passwords to others.  This is not an option for us.

Comment: My point is that it already exposed in places easier to find than an installer log file. I suggest using another way to secure the connection string. Google "Protecting Connection Information" and/or ask a question about that.

Comment: The MSI log file is the only place that I'm aware of where passwords are exposed.  With our software, a SysAdmin could run the installer, but call over a DB Admin to enter install-time credentials so that the SysAdmin can then use those credentials to create/use an already created run-time DB user.

Comment: Users who run MyApp.exe need read access to MyApp.exe.config. (I don't have an answer about util:XmlFile.)